# Jasmine - How to Spy and test an AngularJS asynchronus Service

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I am trying to spy on an asynchronous service call, however so far not successful. Though the synchronus calls are able to Mock.

```
commonService.getResource(ResourceConst).then(function (result) {
                $scope.resource = result.data;
            }, function (error) {
                loggerService.log(error);
});
```

Actual Get Resource Function

```
function getResource(resourceURL) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var url = resourceURL + ".json";
            $http.get(url).then(function (data) {
                deferred.resolve(data);
            },
                function (error) {
                    deferred.reject(error);
                });
            return deferred.promise;
}
```

Even though I was able to spy on synchronus methods in the same service like below I was not able to do the same for this function call.

```
spyOn(commonService, 'hasData').and.callFake(function(args) {
    return true;
});
```

The above code success fully mocked the synchronus call ,

```
$scope.hasData = commonService.hasData($scope.resource.Data);
```

How can I return a result

**{'name': "Name"}** to the asynchronous call getResource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the service is supposed to return a promise, return value should be mocked with a promise:

```
spyOn(commonService, 'hasData').and.returnValue($q.resolve({'name': "Name"} ));
```

The code above uses deferred antipattern. It should be instead:

```
function getResource(resourceURL) {
            var url = resourceURL + ".json";
            return $http.get(url);
}
```

Comment: Any Idea how could I resolve $q , i get $q.resolve is not a function . I did inject with _$q_

Comment: I did try with this. ```spyOn(commonService, "getResource").and.callFake(function(arg) {
                    var deferred = $q.defer();
                    var result = {data: [{id:'id'}]};
                    deferred.resolve(result);
                    return deferred.promise;
                });``` How ever the then function() part is still not covered

Comment: Deferred antipattern was promoted by jQuery and shouldn't be used almost never. $q.resolve should be there. It isn't available in AngularJS 1.3 and lower, if this isn't so, this means that you've injected it wrong. If you have problems with testing it like shown in the answer, please, provide your current test code. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Yes the project uses AnularJs 1.3

Comment: Use `$q.when` instead of `$q.resolve` then. Notice that you should run a digest cycle in order to have promise chain executed in ngMock unit tests. Make sure you have $rootScope.$digest() before asserting things that should happen inside `then`.